# How to pass data into a RoutedEventHandler function

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events

I'm working on a C# application that utilizes WPF and currently am looking to trigger an event when a TreeViewItem object receives focus. I've implemented this in a very basic manner with the following code:

Assigning the event:

```
TreeViewItem chr = new TreeViewItem();
chr.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(testing);
```

The actual handler:

```
private void testing(object o, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("TESTING");             
}
```

This was simple enough, but I would also like to be able to use data from the object inside the eventhandler method. Something along the lines of this:

```
TreeViewItem chr = new TreeViewItem();
chr.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(testing(chr));
```

I can't quite figure out how to do this and anything I do results in syntax errors. How is this normally done / is it even possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `sender` parameter like the following:

```
private void testing(object o, EventArgs e)
{
     var treeViewItem = o as TreeViewItem;          
}
```

It happens that the sender object is actually the object that fired the event, TreeViewItem for your case

Comment: This one looks super promising. Does this create a deep or shallow copy of the original? I'm on lunch break atm so I'll all these out when I get back and let you know the results.

Comment: It does not create anything. It is the same reference. It is actually the same `chr` that you were trying to pass as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void SomeFunction()
    {
        TreeViewItem chr = new TreeViewItem();
        chr.GotFocus += testing; // Event directly, no wrapper.
    }

    private void testing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // it's RoutedEventArgs, not EventArgs 
    {
        var chr = sender as TreeViewItem; // convert to item
        //do your rest work
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the eventArgs, that was from a previous try. This also looks like what I was trying to implement.

Comment: @HowardP I did not see the big difference with the answer you chose. I provided enough comments to understand, and the answer's event arg is not correct, it should be `RoutedEventArgs`. :)

Comment: taquion's answer also gave some explanation that helped me understand. Your answer is also very good, I cannot accept both unfortunately.

Comment: +1. My apologies @Dongdong, I just wrote my answer and did not see yours sincerely. Although I do not agree on your comment about `EventArgs` is not correct. Since I saw that OP was using a less derived type I did so too... and the language allow this... try yourself.. the second parameter can be even of type `object`.

Comment: @taquion no worries, we just make thing correct. @HowardP, the problem of his code is not only parameter, also event itself, both  `new RoutedEventHandler(testing)` and `new RoutedEventHandler(testing(chr))`are misunderstanding about `delegate`, it's an important point to use `function reference` to deliver `parameters` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the SelectedItemChanged event. Check the next example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tree.SelectedItemChanged += Tree_SelectedItemChanged;

    }

    private void Tree_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(((TreeViewItem)e.NewValue).Header.ToString());
    }
}
```

The method will receive the TreeViewItem in the "NewValue" property of the e parameter so, the MessageBox will display the item label.

Comment: This looks like proper form for doing something like this. Does this change trigger on the new selected item, or on the previously selected element?

Comment: This change trigger on the new selected item.